# Como hago una lista de una clase en C# filtrando variables

Tags: c#

Tengo esta clase

```
 public class Persona
    { 
        private string nombre;
        private string apellido;
        private string telefono;
        private string correo;
        public string Nombre
        {
            get { return nombre; }
            set { nombre = value; }
        }
        public string Apellido
        {
            get { return apellido; }
            set { apellido = value; }
        }
        public string Telefono
        {
            get { return telefono; }
            set { telefono = value; }
        }
        public string Correo
        {
            get { return correo; }
            set { correo = value; }
        }
```

Y quiero mostrar solo el nombre y el correo y los datos almacenados en un datagridview, que metodo debo usar para excluir o incluir solo los campos que mencione?

Comment: Entiendo que tienes una `List<Persona>`. Es asi?

Comment: Si, lo que quiero es filtrar algunas clases y que no aparezca completa

Comment: Te he añadido una respuesta, pruébalo y si tienes dudas comenta en la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero mencionarte que puedes escribir la clase mucho mas corta si usas

```
public class Persona
{ 
    private string Nombre {get;set;}
    private string Apellido {get;set;}
    private string Telefono {get;set;}
    private string Correo {get;set;}
}
```

no hace falta definir las variables privadas

Si usas un `DataGridView` puedes indicar que datos visualizar en tiempo de diseño definiendo la columna

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y a la columna le asignas el `DataPropertyName` indicando el nombre de la propiedad de la clase que quieres visualizar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi puedes controlar desde el control grid que datos visualizar

Comment: Creo que te faltaría añadir que en este caso, sería necesario poner la propiedad `AutoGenerateColumns` false. Salvando esto, creo que esta respuesta es la mas adecuada a lo que pide el op. Mantendré la mia por completar y mostrar otra forma diferente que puede servir en otras ocasiones.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando declaras una nueva instancia de la clase, tienes a disposición todos los miembros de la clase. Si guardas solo uno, el resto tendrá por valor `null` Para hacer referencia a cada miembro simplemente escribes `nombreClase.Miembro`.

```
//Nueva instancia de la clase Persona
Persona persona = new Persona();
//Guardamos los datos del formulario
persona.Nombre = "Mi nombre";
persona.Apellido = "Mi apellido";
persona.Correo = "correo@correo.com";

//Obtenemos nombre y apellidos de la persona
string nombreCompleto = String.Format("{0} {1}", persona.Nombre, persona.Apellido);
string correo = persona.Correo;
//Asignamos un valor por defecto a la variable telefono
string telefono = string.Empty;
//En este caso, como la clase no tiene teléfono, no cambiará su valor.
if (persona.Telefono != null) telefono = persona.Telefono;
```

Comment: No se si esto responde exactamente a lo que pide el OP, dado que parece querer filtrar de una lista, no solo de un objeto de la clase. Pero a ver que dice el usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que tienes una `List<Persona>`. Una manera sencilla para obtener una nueva lista solo con los campos que nos interesen es usar [`Select`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8). Por ejemplo, podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
var listaFiltrada = listaPersonas.Select(x => new { x.Nombre, x.Apellido });
```

En `listaFiltrada` obtendermos una nueva lista (en este caso de un tipo anónimo) sólo con el nombre y el apellido y podremos pasar esta lista al `DatagridView` para que sólo muestre esos campos.